# What are the parameters need to be put inside a Html.BeginForm()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following view:

```
<h2>enter the student name to search</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <label>Search:</label>
  <input type="text" name="searchString" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
}
```

and the view corresponds to following controller

```
namespace Searching.Controllers
{ 
   public class SearchController : Controller
   //somecode

   [HttpPost] 
   public ActionResult SearchIndex(FormCollection formCollection)
   {
      string searchString=formCollection["searchString"];
      var search = from m in db.Searches select m;
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
      {
        search = search.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchString));
      }
      return View(search);
    }
  }
}
```

the controller name is SearchController.cs and the name of the method to pass form is SearchIndex.
What should be the parameter inside the Html.BeginForm().I am a begginer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Html.BeginForm("SearchIndex", "Search", .....)
```

You should read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410596.aspx

Comment: I agree, could you not just have googled. `Html.BeginForm example`